# Do you go there often? / Do you often go there?

Tags: word-order

Which one is correct or used often, or is there no difference?
A. Do you go there often?
B. Do you often go there?

How about these two sentences?
C. Do you go there usually?
D. Do you usually go there?

Comment: A and B are both idiomatic, with slightly different emphases which will probably make one or the other the preferred choice in certain contexts. C sounds less idiomatic than D, but is not incorrect and might even  be the preferred choice on very rare occasions. / Note that merely swapping a prepositional phrase for 'there' may markedly affect preferences.

Comment: Regarding the emphasis, I can't explain why but it feels like   *B. Do you often go there?* places extra emphasis on *often*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Would you care to unpack your last sentence (the one beginning with "Note"? If I find it a bit cryptic, I imagine the OP does too. Perhaps giving an example or two might be helpful. Don

Comment: @rhetorician I would guess that he meant a sentence like _Do you go to church often?_ instead of _Do you go there often?_.

Comment: @JK2 Thank you; adverbs don't sound good after heavy PPs in particular (??/*_Do you go to the small supermarket which opened a few years ago on the other side of the river often/usually?_)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my 2 cents.

> A. Do you go there often?
>
> B. Do you often go there?

If the speaker is not sure whether the listener 'goes there' at all, much less whether the going there occurs 'often' or not, the speaker would probably say "B".

But if the speaker already knows that the listener 'goes there' and just wants to also know whether the going there occurs 'often' or not, the speaker would probably say "A".

The same goes for C vs. D, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The frequency adverbs go before the main verb. You always get up early, but sometimes you may you use that adverb in some other place of the sentence to emphasiser. You get up always early. Always you get up early.